# Is it mandatory to set databinding obejct to null inside onDestroyView()?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I read some articles where it is said that the best practice is to set `databinding` obejct to null inside `onDestroyView()` in a fragment:

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    dataBinding = null
}
```

I've also seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i50I6RD33nU) where this practice is not even mentioned. I personally don't understand if this practice makes sense or not. Please provide some info about this issue because I really don't know how to go further. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not necessary. `databinding` is just auto generated by compile system. You can go to see the generated source code. Just use `databinding` object as same as common propertys.

Comment: I'll wait also for other answers and if I don't get a better one, I'll mark your as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not mandatory but if you don't it could lead to memory leaks.

`Fragment's lifecycle` is different from `Fragment's view lifecycle`.

Consider the following example:

```
onCreate()
onCreateView()
onDestroyView()
onCreateView()
onDestroyView()
onDestroy()
```

In this case the user did an action which sent the fragment into the backstack then he pressed the back button. `onCreateView` has been called twice therefore two instances of `dataBinding` of which the first one has not been garbage collected. Of course the difference won't be noticeable in this case but if you have a big backstack you need to consider releasing all of your `View references` inside `onDestroyView`.

Answer (score -1):

Not necessary. Needed for DB close, Network call, Services etc.